# Progress bar value handle form input

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I am using jQuery UI progress bar & I need to handle the value of progress bar form input.

```
<div class="progressbar"></div> <input class="valIn" value="37" />
```

below is the function of progressbar

```
$( ".progressbar" ).progressbar({
     value: 37
});
```

I just need to handle the value form out side of function, form the input tag.

Comment: Any one new how to handle the value form input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to get the value from an input element? Then try this:

```
var x = parseInt($(".valIn").val());
$(".progressbar").progressbar({
     value: x
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you need, you should create a function that updates the progressbar value. have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/q3QWh/

click many times on update, you'll see the progress bar moving.

```
var x = 0;

function updateProgressBar(){
    $( ".progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: x });
    x++;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.. but I just need to add value in the input tag & that based on that value the progress bar will increase..